# react router active state on nested navigation

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

I have a 3 level navigation system, a primary and a secondary nav, and clickable buttons on the page. When a link from the primary nav is selected, the secondary nav items are displayed. When the secondary nav items are selected, the page content (below the navigation) changes, and different clickable buttons are displayed. When the clickable buttons are selected, the area where the buttons are (content below the nav) changes, and more details about the clicked button appear.

I'm using react router to handle routing and I want both the primary and secondary nav items to stay selected when the buttons are clicked and the content changes. I'm using the `<Link to='/..' />` component to handle active links and it works for the primary navigation (the clicked item stays selected) and the secondary navigation (when I click on a secondary nav item, it stays selected and the buttons on the page change).

But when I click on the button on the change to show more details, the secondary navigation is not selected anymore (the first nav stays selected)

my routes are like this:

```
    <Route path='/main' component={Component} > // main nav items are here
      <IndexRoute component={Component} />
      <Route // secondary nav items are here
        path=':secondaryCategory'
        component={SecondaryCategory} // this component shows the buttons on the page />
      <Route // clicking on a button will bring the user to this route
        // but the secondaryCategory nav item that was selected gets de-selected
        path=':secondaryCategory/buttons/:buttonId'
        component={Buttons} />
    </Route>
```

the secondaryCategory is the issue here (it's the secondary navigation), the `/main` has its navigation and that one is staying selected, and when I select the main nav item, the secondary nav item stays selected, but once I click a button, the secondary nav doesnt persist its selected state (but the page content changes accordingly, the buttons disappear and I get more details about the button I clicked on)

the link element for clicking on secondary nav items is like this:

```
      <Link
        to={`/main/${secondaryCategory}`} />
```

and the links on the page buttons look like this:

```
    <Link
      to={`/main/${secondaryCategory}/buttons/${buttonId}`} />
```

how can I keep the secondary nav item selected when the page content changes?

Comment: You didn't include it, but you are using either `activeClassName` or `activeStyle` to mark your `<Link>` as active, correct?

Comment: @PaulS yes that's correct

Answer (score 1):

After a lot of trial and error, and reading some blogs/tutorials, I finally came up with the solution:

```
<Route path='/main' component={Component} >
  <IndexRoute component={Component} />

  <Route path=':secondaryCategory'
    component={SecondaryCategory} />

  <Route path='/main/:secondaryCategory'>
    <Route path='buttons/:buttonId' component={Buttons} />
  </Route>
</Route>
```

this will keep both navs' items selected even when the page content is modified.